# Remove rows where a level of a factor occurs only one time in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, unique, subset, r-factor

I have the following sample:

```
Id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3)
long =  c("60.466681", "60.664116", "60.766690", "60.86879", "60.986569","60.466681", "60.664116", "60.766690", "60.86879", "60.986569"  )
data = data.frame(Id, long)
```

I would like to remove the lines where the level of the factor `Id` occurs only one time in the data.frame. For example here, I would remove the row with `Id == 4` and keep the others.

I tried:

```
data$duplicated <- duplicated(data$Id)
subset(data, data$duplicated == "FALSE")
```

but this also removes the row when each factor occurs for the first 
time (i.e. the first rows with `Id=1` or `Id=2`)

```
  Id      long duplicated
1  1 60.466681      FALSE
2  1 60.664116       TRUE
3  2 60.766690      FALSE
4  2  60.86879       TRUE
5  2 60.986569       TRUE
6  1 60.466681       TRUE
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Try `gdata::duplicated2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
data2<-ddply(data,.(Id),function(x){
  if(nrow(x)==1){
    return(NULL)
    }
  else{
    return(x)
  }
})

> data2
  Id      long
1  1 60.466681
2  1 60.664116
3  1 60.466681
4  2 60.766690
5  2  60.86879
6  2 60.986569
7  3 60.766690
8  3  60.86879
9  3 60.986569
```

Comment: That would do the trick, thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work with big files (15 millions rows), there is a ram issue that I usually don´t have!